# Test ClientPortal in Next.JS using Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, next.js

I'm using NextJS and I'm trying to test the `ClientPortal` component. I'm using Jest and React Testing Library for testing.

Here's the `ClientPortal` component:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

export default function ClientPortal({ children, selector }) {
  const ref = useRef();
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = document.querySelector(selector);

    setMounted(true);
  }, [selector]);

  return mounted ? createPortal(children, ref.current) : null;
}
```

How can this be tested using Jest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure the `testEnvironment` configuration is `jsdom`. For jestjs v26, it's `jsdom` by default. For jestjs v27, follow this [guide](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#jest-27) to setup the `testEnvironment` configuration.

The test method is very straightforward. Create a DOM container to store the portal. Query the DOM element and assert whether it exists.

`index.jsx`:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

export default function ClientPortal({ children, selector }) {
  const ref = useRef();
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = document.querySelector(selector);

    setMounted(true);
  }, [selector]);

  return mounted ? createPortal(children, ref.current) : null;
}
```

`index.test.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import ClientPortal from './';

function TestChild() {
  return <div>child</div>;
}
describe('69550058', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const main = document.createElement('main');
    const portalContainer = document.createElement('div');
    portalContainer.id = 'portal-container';
    document.body.appendChild(portalContainer);
    const { container } = render(
      <ClientPortal selector={'#portal-container'}>
        <TestChild />
      </ClientPortal>,
      { container: document.body.appendChild(main) }
    );
    expect(screen.getByText(/child/)).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(portalContainer.innerHTML).toEqual('<div>child</div>');
    expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`<main />`);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/69550058/index.test.jsx (8.941 s)
  69550058
    ✓ should pass (33 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.jsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        9.624 s, estimated 11 s
```

package versions:

```json
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @slideshowp2, it works like a charm! Could you explain what this `expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot("<main />");` does?

Comment: @Akash Assert that the container for `ClientPortal` is empty. If the container contains other components, it can match the rendering structure of other components. But for this simple example, you can remove this assertion.